# Selected Items won't bind to observable Collection

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am trying to populate an Observable Collection Based on What items are selected from the AutoCompleteBox. May I get some guidance towards where I am going wrong. It's not Binding the way I would like it to.
xaml:

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox x:Name="RadAmortAutoBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedItems="{Binding AmortDates, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Payments}" DisplayMemberPath="PaymentNo" TextSearchPath="PaymentNo" Width="708" />
```

ViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<int> amortDates;

    public ObservableCollection<int> AmortDates
    {
        get { return amortDates; }
        set
        {
            amortDates = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("AmortDates");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would you like it to bind then? No one can help you unless you explain what you need help with. What is it that doesn't work?

Comment: I'm trying to Bind to the ObservableCollection which is AmortDates. ObservableCollection isn't being populated.

Comment: How are you setting DataContext?

Comment: Here we subscribed to the "SelectionChanged" event code-behind side and forwarded the selection our viewmodel.

Comment: `public MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();`
`DataContext = vm;`

Comment: And how are you setting values to `AmortDates` property?

Comment: Setting of AmortDates is from above code..... or comes from bindings]

Comment: It cannot come from this `public MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();`  because you are creating a new instance. vm here will be empty. What I asked is there should be somewhere in the code you should be assigning value to AmortDates like this `AmortDates = somecollection`. How are you doing it?

Comment: Actually you are completely wrong. I don't need to assign values like that. That's where binding comes into play. I never had to set it "=" to something. using MVVM and bindings substitute that.

Comment: Yes I agree to your point but your property 'AmortDates` is empty. You are binding an empty property to a control.

Comment: Also you can try setting `SelectedItems="{Binding AmortDates, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: Tried that also. =( `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: Like I said before that is because your `ObservableCollection` is empty