# Binding Selecteditems Autocompletebox to a list

Tags: c#, mvvm

Hello Currently I have a Autocompletebox that's populated with `Payments` and I am currently able to select `PaymentNo` but my next question is how do i `Bind` the selecteditems to a list or an observable collection so I can do further calculations with those values that are selected.

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox 
   x:Name="RadAmortAutoBox" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Payments}" 
   DisplayMemberPath="PaymentNo" 
   TextSearchPath="PaymentNo" 
   Width="708" />
```

Comment: I downvoted because the op has asked this question already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585009/selected-items-wont-bind-to-observable-collection#comment32610536_21585009

Comment: Maybe because your answers weren't in the right directions, atleast not yet and i was trying to see someone elses opinion.

Comment: You should downvote if the answer was already avaialble in the previous post. Thanks @ElectricRouge

Comment: If my answers were not satisfying you should wait till someone else answer your question. Your question was asked only an hour ago.

Comment: I rather see a non bias and influenced answer. Based on their own opinions and facts, the timeline doesn't play a factor. I rather get results quicker hence you see suggestions by justin pihony that differ from yours!

Comment: And I didn't see progress with the other one, hence I made a new one. Age of a post matters fyi.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by `non bias and influenced answer. Based on their own opinions and facts` and **FYI** `Are you creating the collection anywhere? It will be null by default of course` this sounds like a same thing I asked you. Anyhow I hope you find a solution to your problem quickly.

Comment: I would assume no, those are the only places that AmortDates are being initialized. I thought `set
            {
                amortDates= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("AmortDates");
            }` creates the collection per selection.

Comment: But if you didnt realize. they asked it first. And you posted it after they did. And it's okay if you don't know what it means.

Comment: From where I come from 1 hour ago is greater than 40 mins ago. I dont like to spam the comment section further

Comment: Maybe from where you come from you can also see that `non bias and influenced answer. Based on their own opinions and facts` and FYI `Are you creating the collection anywhere? It will be null by default of ` are not 1 hour ago and 40 mins ago. Yeah I would appreciate the spam cut. Cause clearly I was referring to DIFFERENT answers.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radautocompletebox-features-key-properties.html), just bind to the `SelectedItems` property

Comment: i Tried this `public ObservableCollection<int> AmortDates { get; set; }` 
and `Selecteditems="{Binding AmortDates}"` But AmortDates not populating with selections.

Comment: Try setting the `Mode` to `TwoWay`

Comment: Tried that also =( `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Are you creating the collection anywhere? It will be null by default of course